# Jquery: Add a class on jquery spinner value changed

Tags: jquery, spinner

**What i have done:**

```
$( function() {
    var spinner = $( '#spinner' ).spinner({
        min     : -1,
        max     : 1,
        spin    : function( event, ui ) {
            console.log( ui.value );
        }
    });
});

<input id="spinner" name="value">
```

**I want this result:**

```
If spinner value > 1 && spinner selected class == 'ui-spinner-up' addclass this.'active'
If spinner value == 0 removeclass 'active'
If spinner value < 0 && spinner selected class == 'ui-spinner-down' addclass this.'active'
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3zJP.png)

**Does anybody know how to do this? Hope you can understand the question. Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are trying to do something like this-

```
$('#spinner').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val > 1){
        $(this).addClass('ui-spinner-up');
        $(this).removeClass('ui-spinner-down');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }else if(val == 0 ){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('ui-spinner-down');
        $(this).removeClass('ui-spinner-up');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. But how can i use jQuery Spinner - https://jqueryui.com/spinner/

Comment: Click on **view source**  under the example of the [given url](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/). They explained it clearly with an example.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this: ( add jquery-ui.css, jquery-ui.js, jquery.js)**

```
$( function() {    

    var spinner = $( '#spinner' ).spinner({
        min     : -1,
        max     : 1,
        spin    : function( event, ui ) {
            var val = ui.value;

            if( val > 0 ) {
                $( this ).parent().find( 'a.ui-spinner-up' ).addClass( 'active' ).siblings( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            } else if( val < 0 ) {
                $( this ).parent().find( 'a.ui-spinner-down' ).addClass( 'active' ).siblings( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            } else {
                $( this ).parent().find( 'a' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            }

        }
    });

});
```

**html:**

```
<input id="spinner" name="value">
```

Comment: css: a.active { background: #000;}